# Why does OpenGL ES not support geometry shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, geometry-shader

I read [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83038/geometry-shader-shim-for-opengl-es-2-0) and [there](https://www.anandtech.com/show/6134/khronos-announces-opengl-es-30-opengl-43-astc-texture-compression-clu/2) that OpenGL ES does not support geometry shaders. I just wanted to know if it will be added in the future and if not I'd be interested in why.

Is it a technical limitation of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that OpenGL ES 3.1 can apparently use [geometry shaders](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_geometry_shader.txt)

Comment: OpenGL 3.1 can use compute shaders. 3.2 can use geometry and tessellation shader. See https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glCreateShader.xhtml

Comment: But never use geometry shaders. They are terrible for performance, and nearly every use case that could use geometry shaders can be better implemented using compute shaders.